# Elasticsearch returned fields renaming

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch index , I have field called `category` , and I want to rename it to `cat` in the returned array of objects in stead of array of actual value , something like MySQL `SELECT category as cat`

I tried to use [partial_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-fields.html#partial) 
, it returns an array

```
"partial_fields" : {
   "cat" : {
       "include" : ["category"]
   }
}
```

but it returns

```
"fields": {
   "cat": [
      {
        "category": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

in fact I want it to be something like

```
"fields": {
   "cat": [1]
}
```

is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, unfortunately. You'll have to handle this in your application.